# Why does the Gayatri Mantra NOT end with OM except in Bengal?

Tags: mantras, culture, gayatri-mantra

In Bengal, the Gayatri (Savitri) Mantra always starts with OM and ends with OM. The mantra is thus printed in the very famous book 'Ahnik-Krittya' by Shyamacharan Kaviratna Vidyavaridhi.

But so far as I know, in the other parts of India, the Mantra only starts with OM but does not end with OM; the rest is identical though.

What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: This is something I have also noticed. It's very indeed confusing. Would help if someone explains the same.

Comment: I think title should be in a suitable way.

Comment: Your question is essentially. It is because Shyamacharan Kaviratna Vidyavaridhi and those that follow him...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I could not get you.This mantra is prevalent throughout Bengal. Yes Shyamacharan is very respected here but did he add OM without any basis? That seems highly unlikely for such a giant!

Comment: Title should be did  Shyamacharan Kaviratna Vidyavaridhi followers chant gayatri with additional Om ending..